# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str debug

Tags: python

Btw I'm new to stack overflow

I am creating an ATM in python, except that it runs forever. However I encountered a problem with the code. The error says:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Here is my code (or at least the part where it stopped working):

```
def username_and_password2():
    balance_function = ''
    z = 0
    y = 1
    while True:
        e = input("What is your username: ")
        if e in security:
            b = input("What is the password: ")
            if security[e] == b:
                d = list(b)
                while True:
                    if d[z] == ':':
                        break
                    else:
                        z = z+1
                        continue
                while True:
                    if b[z] == ':':
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                for i in range(z,len(b)):
                    balance_function = balance_function+str(d[z]+y)
                    y = y+1
                return balance_function
                print("Access granted\n")
                break
            else:
                print(security[e])
                print("Invalid password\n")
        else:
            print("Invalid username\n")
```

Could you please tell me where Im going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest also mentioning the complete stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs here:

```py
for i in range(z,len(b)):
    balance_function = balance_function+str(d[z]+y)
```

`d[z]` is a `string` and `y` is an `int`. You need to do this instead:

```py
balance_function = balance_function+str(d[z]+str(y))
```